# Cannot serve static files with express routing and no trailing slash

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I want a route called 'main' which will serve static files:

```js
app.use('/main',express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

However when i do:

```
http://my.site.dev/main
```

The CSS and JS files won't download because it is trying to get them from

```
http://my.site.dev/css/styles.css
```

It should be getting the files from:

```
http://my.site.dev/main/css/styles.css
```

However, if I access my site with a trailing slash:

```
http://my.site.dev/main/
```

All files come through fine

Any ideas why not having a trailing slash messes up resources like CSS and JS from coming in?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is an http problem, not just an Express-related challenge. The problem is discussed at:

- [Relative URLs and trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457885/relative-urls-and-trailing-slashes)
- http://www.bizcoder.com/the-mystery-of-the-trailing-slash-and-the-relative-url

If your URL is /main and your relative URL is css/style.css, it will resolve to /css/style.css; but if your URL is /main/, the relative URL resolves to /main/css/style.css.

My strategy for dealing with this is to redirect to add the trailing slash. Like this in Express:

```
app.all(/^\/main$/, function(req, res) { res.redirect('/main/'); });
app.use('/main/',express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

Or:

```
app.enable('strict routing');
app.all('/main', function(req, res) { res.redirect('/main/'); });
app.use('/main/',express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

Comment: To redirect all routes without trailing / to the same url with trailing / you can use:

    app.use(/.*[^\/]$/, function (req, res, next) {
        res.redirect(req.originalUrl+'/');
    });

The regex `/.*[^\/]$/` will match all urls without trailing /

PS: If someone can fix my markup, please do. I don't know why my code is not in a code block

Comment: I didn't have any luck with @kel's comment. It ended up producing one route that worked and one that didn't which was identical to the working route plus a trailing slash for all static content. Trevor's answer seems to work however.

Answer (score 2):

How are the JS/CSS files requested in the HTML? If you're using strings like `css/styles.css`, then it will try to get them from the current directory. The directory for `/main` is `/` (just like `/main.html` would be), while the one for `/main/` is `/main/`. A quick fix would be to use `/main/css/styles.css` in your HTML.

Comment: I'm using:
    <link href="css/styles.css" />
It doesn't make sense to use the full path in the link href

Comment: Personally I always use full paths for assets as I never debug using the `file://` protocol. At any rate, you're limited to a few options here: (1) use the full path to the assets; (2) use a middleware or something in Express to ensure that a trailing slash always exists; (3) use a local when you render to tell your layout which path to use, e.g. in Jade `link(href="#{subdir}/css/styles.css")` (4) use `<base href />` in the HTML to set the base URI manually (seems like the worst solution).

Comment: im not using the file:// protocol, my site is hosted locally with http://my.site.dev/main

Comment: If that's the case, why wouldn't it make sense to use the full path? If you use a relative path, you'll get different results for every subpath (e.g., relative paths from `/main`, `/main/something`, and `/main/something/else` are all different).

Comment: In apache you can provide an alias in the conf file that points a path off the main url to a directory in the filesystem. You don't ever need to mention the alias path name in your script includes because root always points to that directory.  I want the same functionality in node.js/connect/express with the non trailing slash.  Im thinking it's some regex thing or i need to redirect main to main/ ?