# Nancy navigation to URL without trailing slash?

Tags: url, path, nancy

We are using Nancy framework for our application which is self-hosted in console application.
The problem appears when loading the URL without trailing slash.

Let's say we are hosting the page in

```
http://host.com:8081/module/
```

It then serves us am html page which has resources with a relative path like this:

```
content/scripts.js
```

Everything works well when you enter a url such as

```
// Generates a resource url 'http://host.com:8081/module/content/scripts.js' 
// which is good
http://host.com:8081/module/
```

But when we leave out a trailing slash, the resource url is

```
// Generates a resource url 'http://host.com:8081/content/scripts.js' 
// which is bad
http://host.com:8081/module
```

Is there any way to make redirection to trailing slash version? Or at least detect if trailing slash exists or not.

Thanks!

Comment: You could probably hook into the Before application pipeline and add the trailing slash or do theredirecct

Comment: Hooking to the Before doesn't work because I get the same URL when accessing URL with or without trailing slash. I can't detect when trailing slash is missing and when do the redirect.

Comment: If I create two routes, `Get["/module"]` and `Get["/module/"]`, then requests for both _/module_ and _/module/_ get handled by the  `Get["/module/"]` route - so there appears to be no way to distinguish between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels a bit hacky but it works:

```
Get["/module/"] = o =>
{
    if (!Context.Request.Url.Path.EndsWith("/"))
        return Response.AsRedirect("/module/" + Context.Request.Url.Query, RedirectResponse.RedirectType.Permanent);
    return View["module"];
};
```

The `Request` accessible from `Context` lets you see whether the path has the trailing slash or not and redirect to a 'slashed' version.
I wrapped this up as an extension method (which works for my very simple use case):

```
public static class NancyModuleExtensions
{
    public static void NewGetRouteForceTrailingSlash(this NancyModule module, string routeName)
    {
        var routeUrl = string.Concat("/", routeName, "/");
        module.Get[routeUrl] = o =>
        {
            if (!module.Context.Request.Url.Path.EndsWith("/"))
                return module.Response.AsRedirect(routeUrl + module.Request.Url.Query, RedirectResponse.RedirectType.Permanent);
            return module.View[routeName];
        };
    }
}
```

To use in a module:

```
// returns view "module" to client at "/module/" location
// for either "/module/" or "/module" requests
this.NewGetRouteForceTrailingSlash("module");
```

[This is worth reading though before going with a solution such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5458025/998793)