# relative URL seems to be interpreted incorrectly by the browser

Tags: href, relative-url

I have a relative URL on a page, which is being interpreted relative to the root (instead of relative to the current doc). Can't figure out why.

On page:

```
http://vm:8080/docs
```

There is a tag:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="_sources/index.txt">Show Source</a>
```

The browser resolves this to:

```
http://vm:8080/_sources/index.txt
```

Instead of:

```
http://vm:8080/docs/_sources/index.txt
```

Here is some information for the anchor from the DOM.

```
origin     http://vm:8080
baseURI    http://vm:8080/docs
pathname   /_sources/index.txt
href       http://sanjay-vm:8080/_sources/index.txt
```

Why is the browser adding a leading slash to the pathname?

Comment: what if you force it by using `./path` instead of `/path`

Comment: The href is "path" not "/path". And, yes, that would be a possibility. But I just want to understand why the browser is behaving this way. Besides, in this case, this is from htm generated by a tool, and it's not easy to change the hrefs it generates.

Comment: if it is generated by `sphinx` then maybe an update should solve the problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Sphinx is generating correct relative URLs. The browser, for some reason, seems to be misinterpreting the relative URLs. I do have the latest version of Sphinx BTW.

Comment: if it is the same behavior from all browsers, then the problem must be from generating them (sphinx)

Comment: In your page url `http://vm:8080/docs` the browser doesn't use 'docs' in the relative url because it has no trailing slash.  See the answer to this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457885/relative-urls-and-trailing-slashes