# Relative links on pages without trailing slash

Tags: html

On pages that has no trailing slashes in their URL, is there any way to use relative links that will keep the page in the url?

For example, the link

```
a href="content"
```

on the page

```
http://www.domain.com/page/
```

will link to:

```
http://www.domain.com/page/content
```

But the same link on the page:   (notice the missing slash)

```
http://www.domain.com/page
```

will link to:

```
http://www.domain.com/content
```

Since my website has no trailing slash (second example), I can't use relative links and must use the full path (`a href="/page/content"`).

Comment: You've answered your own question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't find your comment useful. Perhaps my question was not clear enough?

Comment: My understanding of your question is that the link will indeed point to /page/content relative to /page. The trailing slash does not have to be on /page for the link to point to /page/content rather than /pagecontent as you might expect. If that is not what you mean by trailing slash, then your question may be unclear indeed.

Comment: The link will point to /content because there is no slash after page. I will edit my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 8):

Other than including a trailing slash in the link in the first place, or redirecting from paths missing a trailing slash, you may also set the base tag such that it always includes a trailing slash and the current path.

```
<head>
  <base href="/page/" target="_self">
</head>
```

Then relative links should work as anticipated as long as the browser supports this. It is also possible to fully qualify the path.  You may not be able to set this dynamically with javascript.

Answer (score -2):

Relative paths work relative to the folders in which the html page is located.

So for instance, if you are within domain.com's public_html, and there is a folder called page. Then your link whatever is going to link to domain.com/page/content.

Similarly, if you were on a route like domain.com/page where you your link was featured as content.
Clicking that link would take you to domain/page/content.
Further reading:
http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

```
<a href="linkhere.html">Click Me</a>
This link points to a filename, with no path provided. This means that linkhere.html is located in the same folder as the page where this link appears.
If both files were located in the root directory of the Website http://www.website.com,
 the actual website address the user would be taken to is http://www.website.com/linkhere.html. 
If both files were located in a subfolder of the root directory called files, the user would be taken to http://www.website.com/files/linkhere.html.
How about another example? Let's say we our http://www.website.com domain had a subfolder called pictures. Inside the pictures folder is a file called pictures.html. The full path to this page would be:
"http://www.website.com/pictures/pictures.html"
Still with us? Good. Let's say in this pictures.html file, we have a link:
<a href="morepictures.html">More Pictures</a>
If someone clicked that, where do you think it would take them? 
If you said http://www.website.com/pictures/morepictures.html, you'd be right! 
You probably know why it would take them there: 
because both files are saved in the pictures subfolder.
```

Comment: Relative links are resolved based on the URL of the page on which they are served, not based on the server filesystem.

Answer (score -3):

```
a href="./content"
```

you can try this

Comment: Unfortunately ./ at start of the URL does not have any impact. Enforcing access with "/" in the end or using full links instead of relative ones seems to be the only solution here. It is quite annoying for pages, that have mixed content of directory listings and files. (slash and non-slash valid content).