# Browser sends unexpected (incorrect?) requests to load a resource if the path fragment in the address bar has no trailing slash

Tags: html, browser, request

I've got a server that serves an html-page when `/path/to/my/page` endpoint is requested.

The page contains the following link:

```html
<link href="styles/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So when the page is loaded, I expect browser to request `/path/to/my/page` + `styles/default.css` => `/path/to/my/page/styles/default.css`.

But it requests `/path/to/my/styles/default.css` instead.

I guess that there must be some techniques to make it do what I want, but I'm not aware of them and I don't really know what the actual question is.

Answer (score 0):

[Relative links on pages without trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111257/relative-links-on-pages-without-trailing-slash)

Basically, pathname with no trailing slash implies that the loaded resource is a file in a directory delimited by prev `/` of the root. Checked the network tab. `page` was the generated filename of an html returned by the server.