# links relative to current url without slash nor extension at the end

Tags: html

I have this html saved as `test` (without extension)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="link">link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

File is saved in subdirectory `aa` of local root server directory so in browser it is available with http://localhost/aa/test . Base href is set to '/' as this is required by framework I use.

I'd like to define link as relative to current url (http://localhost/aa/test/link) but browser combine as relative to current directory (http://localhost/aa/link). How can I achieve this without using any scripting ? I'd like to avoid putting part of current path into href attribute.

**edit**

1. added base href
2. added doctype

Comment: Either use a `base` element, or modify the `href` attribute accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried this `<a href="test/link">link</a>` ?

Comment: @CBroe added base href to html as I need it.

Comment: @d.coder I'd like to avoid putting part of current path into href attribute.

Comment: Well then there isn’t much you can do – you need to either supply the correct relative URL in the `href` attribute, or use some kind of script.

Comment: Check this other question on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296873/basic-html-how-to-set-relative-path-to-current-folder) if it answers your question:

Comment: @dvsakgec how did you obtain the ability to comment with 1 reputation point? I'm just curious.

Comment: Kind of contradictory, isn't it? On one hand, you need to refer all the URLs to the root, due to your framework (Which is it?). And on another hand, you need the URLs to be relative to the current. I'd suggest to tune the framework properly, better...

Comment: Can't be done. Detailed explanation is in [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457885/relative-urls-and-trailing-slashes) answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative URLs and trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457885/relative-urls-and-trailing-slashes)