# create-react-app "homepage": "." does not use correct relative path from index.html when using aws api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, create-react-app

I have a static website hosted on s3.

static hosted link generated by aws (Not using this):

```
http://example-s3.s3-website.{region}.amazonaws.com
```

actual resource path:

```
https://example-s3.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/index.html
```

[image]

And using api-gateway HTTP proxy integration,
I've set the following integration:

```
www.example.com/test/{proxy+} -> https://example-s3.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/{proxy}
```

So, `www.example.com/test` would point to `index.html` (default page)

From the CRA documentation section ["Serving the Same Build from Different Paths"](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/):

I've set

```
"homepage": ".",
```

such that the website uses `www.example.com/test`, aka `https://example-s3.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/` as the root directory (relative to index.html as indicated by the document)

However, this fails to fetch any css, or js.

If i look at the console, it gets 404 because it is trying to get the resources from `www.example.com/` not `www.example.com/test`.

So the above package.json configuration is not working for some reason.

I have changed the config to hard-code the url:

```
"homepage": "www.example.com/test",
```

Now it can fetch all the resources fine.

My question is though, why doesn't `"homepage": ".",` setting work?!
This setting and `"homepage": "www.example.com/test",` should be identical
as index.html is served at `www.example.com/test` (aka `https://example-s3.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/index.html`)

But CRA for some reason thinks `"homepage": ".",` is infact `"homepage": "www.example.com",`

Comment: That is strange. Can you go to /test/ with the trailing slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue lies in your trailing slash [Relative URLs and trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457885/relative-urls-and-trailing-slashes)

This should works fine, I create one configuration just the same with you. With trailing slash, it works. **It won't work without**

https://xswprgicvd.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/app/

[image]

[image]
[image]

Edit: Added images added by qkhanhpro in the comment section.

Comment: I am getting access denied error with the trailing slash and fine without the trailing slash.

How are you loading css, image files on S3 with the trailing slash? 
for an instance:
`https://example.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/file.png` loads fine
`https://example.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/file.png/` will always yield access error.

Comment: Note that AWS apig does not support trailing slash officially and proxy is just a workaournd:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=242423.

I'd expect the relative URL to work fine without the trailing slash - espeically if the documentation says it uses the path relative to index.html...
Though workaround doesn't work for me neither due to the access error.

Comment: Confirmed that https://example.com/test/index.html works but not https://example.com/test. So I can't use default page if I use '"homepage": "."' ...

Comment: I updated the example with the image so that you can see how images react : )   <img src="asset/sample.jpg"></img>

Comment: your `/app/{proxy+}` integration is set to `https://example.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/{proxy}` right?

how are you avoiding the access error?
I have the same img path as yours.

Comment: I am not on the PC now. Can send you my config as image in 1 hour or so

Comment: Thanks, it's hard to see why your settings work when `https://example.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/file.png/` trailing slash is also passed. 

Perhaps its to do with "Error document setting - index.html" setting? That's the only difference I have with you.

By the way it would probably the best if the image is pasted inside the stackoverflow solution, not imgur, as the image can be deleted later.

I tried editing your answer to add the pictures but SO says the edit queue is full..
Many thanks again.